# How to loop through a JSON object in Perl?

Tags: json, perl

I'm trying to create an api using perl, the api is for a react native, when the user submits a form on the app I'll get the following object,
I'm new to perl and I'm lost trying to loop thro the object :/

```
{
    checkboxes: [
        {
            id: "1",
            fullname: "Name 1",
            color: "red",
            res: false
        },
        {
            color: "green",
            fullname: "Name 2",
            id: "2",
            res: false
        },
        {
            color: "blue",
            id: "3",
            fullname: "Name 3",
            res: false
        }
    ]
}
```

my $data_decoded       = decode_json($data);

I'm trying this loop, but it only prints the full object.

```
foreach $a (@data) {
   print "value of a: $a\n";
}
```

Comment: You mean `for (@{ $data->checkboxes })`?

Comment: @ikegami Thats where I'm confuse, because $data is what I getting and I was reading that I have to use 'decode_json' but after that I lost on how to access the information.

Comment: I meant `$You mean for (@{ $data_decoded->checkboxes })` (I would have named `$data` `$json`. It makes no sense to use `_decoded` everywhere.)

Comment: Try `for my $checkbox (@{ $data_decoded->checkboxes }) { print "Color: ", $checkbox->{color}, "\n"; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You turned your JSON into a reference Perl data structure with `decode_json` (from somewhere, and Mojo::JSON is such a place):

```
use Mojo::JSON qw(decode_json);
my $data = ...;
my $data_decoded = decode_json($data);
```

Now you have to figure out how to access whatever you have in `$data_decoded`. You can look at its structure by dumping it

```
use Mojo::Util qw(dumper);
print dumper( $data_decoded );
```

You'll see that the Perl structure is the same as the JSON structure. You have a hash (JSON's Object) that has a `checkboxes` key that points to an array. The array elements are hashes.

Using Perl v5.24's [postfix dereferencing notation](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/), you get all of the array elements:

```
# uglier circumfix  notation @{$data_decoded->{checkboxes}}
my @elements = $data_decoded->{checkboxes}->@*;
```

You might put that in a loop:

```
foreach my $hash ( $data_decoded->{checkboxes}->@* ) {
   ...
   }
```

Now you get each hash element in `$hash` and you can do whatever you like with it. <s>That part you haven't told us about yet. :)</s>

The [Perl Data Structures Cookbook (perldsc)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc) has a lot of examples of the generation and iteration of various combinations of hash and array references.

---

You say that you want to do something when the value of the `res` key is true. In that case, you can use `next` to skip the items where `res` is false:

```
foreach my $hash ( $data_decoded->{checkboxes}->@* ) {
   next unless $hash->{res};
   say "I'm doing something when res is true";
   }
```

Comment: Thank you, What I'm trying to do with the data is if res is true, update a table.

Answer (score 1):

Following demo code demonstrates looping through these particular data

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $input = do { local $/; <DATA> };
my $data  = from_json($input);

say Dumper($data);

for my $obj ( @{$data->{checkboxes}} ) {
    say join(",\t", $obj->@{qw/id fullname color/});
}

__DATA__
{
    "checkboxes": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "fullname": "Name 1",
            "color": "red",
            "res": false
        },
        {
            "color": "green",
            "fullname": "Name 2",
            "id": "2",
            "res": false
        },
        {
            "color": "blue",
            "id": "3",
            "fullname": "Name 3",
            "res": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'checkboxes' => [
                            {
                              'res' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ),
                              'color' => 'red',
                              'fullname' => 'Name 1',
                              'id' => '1'
                            },
                            {
                              'fullname' => 'Name 2',
                              'color' => 'green',
                              'res' => $VAR1->{'checkboxes'}[0]{'res'},
                              'id' => '2'
                            },
                            {
                              'id' => '3',
                              'color' => 'blue',
                              'res' => $VAR1->{'checkboxes'}[0]{'res'},
                              'fullname' => 'Name 3'
                            }
                          ]
        };

1,      Name 1, red
2,      Name 2, green
3,      Name 3, blue
```